# cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Article.article_type of type models.ArticleType

Tags: json, go, go-gorm

I cannot unmarshal json field `article_type` into golang struct `Article`.

I'm getting error:

`json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Article.article_type of type models.ArticleType`

```
str := []byte(`[{"created_at":1486579331,"updated_at":1486579331,"article_type":"news"}]`)

type Article struct {
    ID            uint      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt     timestamp.Timestamp `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt     timestamp.Timestamp `json:"updated_at"`

    ArticleType   ArticleType `json:"article_type"`
    ArticleTypeId uint        `gorm:"index" json:"-"`

type ArticleType struct {
    ID        uint      `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt timestamp.Timestamp `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt timestamp.Timestamp `json:"updated_at"`
    Title     string    `gorm:"size:255" json:"title"`

    Articles  []Article `json:"articles"`
}

articles := []models.Article{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(str, &articles); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

I wanted that `"article_type":"news"` would be parse as:
Article.ArticleType.title = "news"
And then I would can save article object which have article type with title "news" in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your `ArticleType` implement the [json.Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface by defining an `UnmarshalJSON` method on it:

```
func (a *ArticleType) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    a.Title = string(b)
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/k_UlghLxZI